# Assert that a method was called with an object that is changed in the method

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, rhino-mocks

Thats the method I want to test:

```
public void Set1(ViewModelA viewModelA)
{
   var viewModelB = new ViewModelB
   {
      FirstName = viewModelA.FirstName,
      LastName = viewModelB.LastName
   }
   service.Set2(viewModelB);
}
```

How can I assert that the viewModelB instance passed to service.Set2 has the property values mapped from viewModelA and that Set2 took viewModelB as parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you've mocked the `service` instance, you should be able to do something like this:

```
service.AssertWasCalled(s => s.Set2(
  Arg<ViewModelB>.Matches(b =>
    b.FirstName == "TheFirstName" && b.LastName == "TheLastName"
  )
));
```

Essentially what you're doing is asserting that the `Set2` method was called, and was given a `ViewModelB` instance whose first and last name match what you're expecting.